# float value extraction in javascript

Tags: javascript, math, integer

how can i  extract float value like (0.9) to be a whole integer value (9) in JavaScript?

example

```
var total = 67.9; 
something to process  var whole var DEC to be like 
var whole = 67;
var DEC = 9;
```

Comment: why 9 and not 0.9? what should happen with numbers, like 42.321? should it return `dec = 321`?

Comment: numbers like 42.321 should return  42 and  321 not 0.321

Comment: In general case it's not possible (due to finite precision). There is a chance you're doing something in a wrong way and you better explain the original problem you're solving.

Comment: @zerkms It's not possible if you're working with numbers only (and yes, I tried out of curiosity - it almost *never* gives the right answer), but since this is a representation problem we might as well work with strings.

Comment: @MaxArt `var total = 67.9; ` --- well, in the question they are dealing with numbers not strings. Since not every number is correctly representable - you cannot tell (in runtime) whether the numeric literal and its string representation are the same thing.

Comment: @zerkms Indeed, the whole process has its caveats and OP must be aware of them.

Comment: "and OP must be aware" --- I believe they don't care. It's likely they just copy-paste the code from the checked answer and continue doing their job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is this:

```
var string = total.toString();
var dotidx = string.indexOf(".");
var dec = dotidx >= 0 ? +string.slice(dotidx + 1) : 0;
```

Notice that it doesn't work with numbers in exponential forms.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to find a result. I give you one simple solution.

```
var total = 67.9
var splitVal = total.toString().split(".")
var whole = splitVal[0], var desc = splitVal[1] || 0
```

and if you want to convert whole and desc in number then multiply by 1.

```
var whole = splitVal[0] * 1
```

Comment: This would return `undefined`/`NaN` if `total` is actually an integer.

Comment: we can set `var desc = splitVal[1] || 0`. Thanks MaxArt